# Predicting X variables given Y Output in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

Is there a formula in R that allows you to do the following:

What would the x values be to achieve with highest probability a given value of Y. For example, assume my Y variable is a score from 4-10 and my Xs are a series of binomial variables. What would my Xs need to be to ensure I get Y with highest probability.

Comment: In more formal terms, you want to find the mode of the probability distribution of (X1, ..., Xk) conditionally on Y. Please provide some representative example data for `Y`, `X`'s, and let us see any of your attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used expand(), ran each combination through the regression, and then from there sorted to find prediction of choice.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
x1<-c(1:3)
x2<-c(1:5)
test_data<-data.frame(NA)
test_data_<-expand(test_data,x1,x2)

   # A tibble: 15 x 2
      x1    x2
   <int> <int>
 1     1     1
 2     1     2
 3     1     3
 4     1     4
 5     1     5
 6     2     1
 7     2     2
 8     2     3
 9     2     4
10     2     5
11     3     1
12     3     2
13     3     3
14     3     4
15     3     5
```